# Background image with a draggable second image (layers maybe)

Tags: jquery, ajax, dojo, yui

I need to be able to take a background image and float a second draggable image (should be scalable, but with fixed proportions)  Also the code should be able to 'flatten' the image for photo sharing. Oh, also the floating image should have a dropped shadow to give the illusion of depth. Thanks! Is this possible with jQuery, ajax, Yui or Dojo(other?)? Or am I barking up the wrong proverbial code trunk.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely possible to layer a draggable, scalable, fixed-proportioned image with a drop shadow on top of a background image using jQuery or some other JavaScript library. However, flattening the two into one image for photo sharing will require some server-side code that does the image manipulation.

Comment: Great! If you could let me know how much you would charge I may buy Great! Let mr know if you can do this and I may buy the script from you if you are intrested I'll post it on elance to complete the transaction as I'm aware that this isn't the correct forum. But please send a quote to blanco.lucas at gmail.com. Thanks!

Comment: Wow got some stange iPhone typos there. Sorry! Just send me an email